# Hahn-Banach application on not subspace

Tags: functional-analysis

we are given the following exercise today:
Consider $[0,1]$.
Find a linear functional $F:L^{\infty}([0,1])\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $|F(f)|\leq ||f||_{L^{\infty}}$ and so that $F|_{W}\equiv 1$ where  $W= \{f\in L^{\infty}([0,1])$ $:$ $f=1$ a.e. on $[0,\epsilon]$ $\}$

My approach was to use Hahn banach (here $||f||_{L^{\infty}}$ is the semi-norm) but the problem is that $W$ is not a linear subspace.

Comment: It might not be a linear subspace, but can you think of something related to $W$ which is?

Comment: @BrunoB Sure, $\{ f=0 a.e. \}$, $L^{\infty}([0,1])$.

Comment: What I was hinting at was $\operatorname{span}{W}$, i.e. the set of finite linear combinations of elements of $W$.

Comment: @BrunoB How to define F then?

Comment: You want it to be a linear function, so defining it on the span once you have defined it on $W$ should be straightforward: there's only one value you can give to $F(a_1 f_1 + \dots + a_d f_d)$ given the values $F(f_1)$ through $F(f_d)$ after all.

Comment: Does $W$ really depend on some fixed $\epsilon$ like you defined it? Don't you rather mean $W=\{f\in L^{\infty}([0,1]):\exists\epsilon>0,\;f=1\text{ a.e. on }[0,\epsilon]\}$? The result will then be stronger, but not more difficult to find.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yup that's exactly what I mean. I just need to look at the span of that thing then right? Thanks!

Comment: Right. But the proof is the same: just follow Bruno's hints. (And please correct the definition of $W$ in your post if that is what you meant.)